# Show image on button pressed in another page php

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to show certain image on a page which is open in a tab, only when the other page press a button. I know I can post on the other page, but is it going to be live? Because I am not gonna be refreshing the page at all. My whole plan is to press a button on one page and show live result on an another page without refreshing it. How can I make it possible? I just need the basic idea behind it. Sorry if I made it sound complicated.

Thanks

Comment: Use JavaScript and AJAX

Comment: I would suggest that you need websockets

Comment: @BlobbyBob can you specify what kind of functions I would have to use? Thank you!

Comment: Client: You could use jQuery as simple JS framework for the AJAX requests ( $.ajax({...}) )
Server: Just store in a file, when the button has been clicked and regularly request this file from the client

Comment: Sorry to ruin the party but ajax is not the correct way. It will consume much of the resources because people will suggest to use `setInterval` along with it. The comment by @RamRaider makes much sense for achieving this.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat You don't need to make an AJAX request every second. Instead let the server hold the connection for some time and only send data when the event triggers

Comment: Thanks for giving me the basic ideas behind it, I will go research on both of them!!

Comment: perhaps one of the simplest implementations you could go for is a `node.js` websocket server - plenty of examples to be found and then add your own business logic to the equation

Comment: @BlobbyBob How would you hold the connection in a HTTP request? HTTP is stateless, its request - response. You will need websockets for this task.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat You don't send the response. In PHP you can implement it for example by `while (!cond) {sleep(1);}`

Comment: Use Ajax to achieve this

Comment: @Blobbybob I don't think it is worth a discussion. That's a bad advice because the page won't even load.